# Oracle PL/SQL SQL Injection Test from Unicode to Windows-1252

Tags: sql-injection, oracle, unicode

I have a DB using [windows-1252 character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) and dynamic SQL that does simple single quote escaping like this...

```
l_str := REPLACE(TRIM(someUserInput),'''','''''');
```

Because the DB is windows-1252 when the notorious [Unicode Character 'MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE' (U+02BC)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2bc/index.htm) is sent it gets converted.

Example: The front end app submits this...

```
TESTʼEND
```

But ends up searching on this...

```
and someColumn like '%TESTÊ¼END%'
```

What I want to know is, since the `ʼ` was converted into `Ê¼` (which luckily is safe just yields wrong search results) is there any scenario where a non-windows-1252 characters can be converted into something that WILL break this thus making SQL injection possible?

I know about bind variables, I know the DB should be unicode as well, that's not what I'm asking here.  I am needing proof that what you see above is not safe.  I have searched for days and cannot find a way to cause SQL injection when doing simple single quote escaping like this when the DB is windows-1252.  Thanks!

Oh, and always assuming the column being search is a `varchar`, not `number`.  I am aware of the issues and how things change when dealing with numbers.  So assume this is always the case:

```
l_str := REPLACE(TRIM(someUserInput),'''','''''');
...
... and someVarcharColumn like '%'||l_str||'%'
```